# An array of records inside and array of records in Pascal

Tags: arrays, record, pascal

I'm having problems creating an array of records with an array of records inside.

```
type
    SubjectsRec = array of record
        subjectName : String;
        grade : String;
        effort : Integer;
    end;
    TFileRec = array of record
        examinee : String;
        theirSubjects: array of SubjectsRec;
    end;

var
    tfRec: TFileRec;
    i: Integer;
begin
    setLength(tfRec,10);
    for i:= 0 to 9 do
    begin
       setLength(tfRec[i].theirSubjects,10);
    end;
```

After this I was hoping to assign values by doing this:

```
tfRec[0].theirSubjects[0].subjectName:= "Mathematics";
```

However, I get:

> Error: Illegal qualifier

when trying to compile.

Comment: Please mention what compiler you use.

Comment: @Wes if my answer helped you, would you mind to accept it as the correct one clicking on the big "V" just in the left of the answer? :)

Answer (score 2):

You declared `SubjectsRec` as an array of records, and then declared the `TheirSubjects` field as an array of `SubjectRecs` - that is, `TheirSubjects` is an array of arrays of records.

There are two solutions:

Declare `TheirSubjects` as having the type `SubjectsRec`, instead of `array of subjectsRec`:

```
TFileRec = array of record
  examinee : string;
  theirSubjects: SubjectsRec;
end;
```

or declare `SubjectsRec` as a record, not as an array. This is my favorite one:

```
SubjectsRec = record
  subjectName : String;
  grade : String;
  effort : Integer;
end;
TFileRec = array of record
  examinee : string;
  theirSubjects: array of SubjectsRec;
end;
```

Also, strings in Pascal are delimited by single quotes, so you should replace `"Mathematics"` by `'Mathematics'`.

Comment: IOW, in the original post `tfRec[0].theirSubjects[0][0].subjectName:= "Mathematics";` would work (provided the length of TheirSubjecst[0] is set), but not as what is meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change this:

```
tfRec[0].theirSubjects[0].subjectName:= "Mathematics";
```

to

```
tfRec[0].theirSubjects[0].subjectName:= 'Mathematics';
```